# JavaScript Permutations using Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I know that there are many solutions on the internet for my specific question, but I have been trying to solve it in a specific way and it doesn't work and I really can't understand what is wrong.
In my case I simply want to print the permutations.
Here is my code:

```js
a = "abc";


function f7(a, b) {



  //document.write("str: "+a+" b:"+b+"<br>");
  if (b.length == 2) {
    perm = b + a;
    return perm;
  }

  var c = [];
  var str = [];

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    c[i] = b + a.charAt(i);
    str[i] = a.substring(0, i) + a.substring(i + 1);

    document.write("i: " + i + " c[i]: " + c[i] + " str[i]: " + str[i] + "<br>");

    return f7(str[i], c[i]);


  }


  //return {str,c}

}


document.write(f7(a, ""));

//g=f7(a,""); 
//document.write(g.str+"<br>");
//document.write(g.c+"<br>");
```

The above code doesn't go beyond the first permutation, and I can't understand why.
Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: There is no point in a loop with an unconditional return statement inside it, it can never iterate.

Answer (score 1):

**Returning value in the loop causes escaping the loop**. You are returning the value in `for` statement that stops immediately before loop complete.

You can use temporary variable to save value in for loop, and then return it.

```js
a = "abc";


function f7(a, b) {
  //document.write("str: "+a+" b:"+b+"<br>");
  if (b.length == 2) {
    perm = b + a;
    return perm;
  }

  var c = [];
  var str = [];
  var temp = '';

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i] = b + a.charAt(i);
    str[i] = a.substring(0, i) + a.substring(i + 1);

    document.write("i: " + i + " c[i]: " + c[i] + " str[i]: " + str[i] + "<br>");

    temp += f7(str[i], c[i]);
  }

  return temp
}


document.write(f7(a, ""));

//g=f7(a,""); 
//document.write(g.str+"<br>");
//document.write(g.c+"<br>");
```

Comment: Hi zmag, thanks for the post. I ran it and now I have 2 specific permutations for my case: abc and acb, but there should be 6 in total (bac bca cab cba) - is it possible to get them all?

Comment: If it's not working properly, maybe its algorithm could be the problem.

Comment: in this link: https://initjs.org/all-permutations-of-a-set-f1be174c79f8 there is an algorithm that works, and it has the recursion inside the loop - is it because the recursion is being done with a var and not a return?

Comment: I don't think that implementation is the same as yours. in the link, there are loop having inner loop. what did you intend to make your own code?

Comment: Its just that even before looking for the answer I thought I had an idea about how to do it, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work, s it must mean there is something fundamental which I don't understand, so that's why I want to know what it is